# ¿Es necesario inicializar un objecto en angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, object

Tengo una clase externa `export class` como template para un objeto.

```
export class Car{
  name: Boolean;
  other: {
    prize: String;
    brand: String;
  };
  doors: {
    number: String,
    size: String,
  };
}
```

Intento acceder a ella desde otra clase, por lo que he creado una nueva variable

```
var car= new Car();
```

Como `name` es un `boolean`, doy por hecho que se inicializa con un `true` puesto que es su valor predeterminado. Mi problema viene cuando intento inicializar al objecto `doors` peusto que este no lo tiene.

```
  var car= new Car();
  this.car.doors[pos].number;
```

Cuando intento acceder a el me dice que `undefined`. ¿Cómo podría acceder a él? Imagino que necesito inicializarlo en el constructor.

**No necesito inicializar `other`**

Comment: Es necesario inicializar el objeto doors, una de las soluciones tú mismo la mencionas: un constructor que inicialize doors.

Comment: ¿Cómo lo realizo?

Comment: ¿Usas Typescript?

Comment: Si. Estoy usando typscript con angular 2

Comment: `this.car.doors[pos]`, qué es `pos`? Si es un índice, (Y quieres almacenar varios `doors`) entonces la propiedad `doors` debería ser del tipo `Array<Doors>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Debes inicializarlo en su constructor** si quieres acceder a sus atributos, ya que se trata de un **"Objeto propio"**, te dejo una alternativa:

```
 export class Car{
  name: Boolean;
  other: Others;
  doors: Doors;

 constructor(){
    this.name = (true / false); //Segun te parezca correcto.
    this.other = new Other(); // Inicializas el objeto Other - Opcional, ya que no lo necesitas
    this.doors = new Doors(); // Inicializas el objeto Doors
 }
}
// Alternativa a class Car ------------------------------------
export class Car {
  constructor(public name: Boolean = true,
              public doors: Doors = new Doors(), 
              public other: Other = new Other()){}

// Esto te permite tener un constructor al que le podrías pasar parámetros y si no lo haces por defecto utiliza lo que se encuentra a la derecha del =
//--------------------------------------------------------------
export class Doors{
    number: String;
    size: String;
}
export class Other {
    prize: String;
    brand: String;
}
```

---

```
var car= new Car(); // Ya te permitiría ingresar a Doors y Others (si fuese necesario)
```

Las variables dentro de `Other` y `Doors`, van a ser `undefined` si intentas accederlas, ya que no se le asigna ningún valor.

Comment: Disculpa, estaba editando porque vi el error y se puso pantalla azul (Windows life), ya lo vuelvo a editar.